# How to pronounce the programmer's abbreviation "char"

Tags: terminology, pronunciation, abbreviations, programming, cultural-correctness

In many programming languages, *char* is a type name for character values. The word *character* is pronounced with a [k] sound, but what about *char*?

While trying to find the answer elsewhere, I learnt that there is an English word *char* which is pronounced [tʃɑ:(r)], but it has nothing to do with characters.

How would you read the following piece of code out loud?

```
char a;
```

Is it [kær], [tʃær] or [tʃɑ:(r)]? I've always used the last but I have no idea whether it's correct.

Comment: This has no definitive answer. Some people pronounce it *care* while others pronounce it *char*. Some people say *jif* for "Gif" while others use the hard "g" there. I don't bother correcting anyone (although I do say *care* and *gif* myself).

Comment: @Robusto: That, in itself, is an answer to my question.

Comment: I've never heard any native English speaker call the *char* datatype *care* or *car*. It's always pronounced as the first syllable in *charming*, despite the fact that it's obviously an abbreviation for *character*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I 100% agree.  char star rhymes.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I dont know if a regional bias comes here again. But most people, (using AmE), I have met, say "kar", since after all, it is the abbreviation of character, which is pronounced with 'k'. Its usage usually sounds like you set off to say 'character', but didnt utter the sounds attributed to the last 5 letters.

Comment: @karthik: Exactly. And then you have the cases where it's in combination with other syllables (charCode, charCodeAt, etc.) where pronouncing it FF's way seems very strange to my ear.

Comment: I just asked the first five developers I ran across in my office and all pronounce it *care*.

Comment: @Robusto: As I've said in the past, Americans tend to go for more "literal" spellings/pronunciations. Plus they drink *Koffee* where Brits have a nice cup of *Cha*, so maybe that explains your version. All I can say is I Googled **"char datatype youtube"** and listened to [this guy](http://www.yourepeat.com/watch/?v=02rP04NI2gY). I had to listen to 1m 40s of his heavy American accent before he finally said *"char"*, but there's no mistaking it's my version, not yours.

Comment: @Fumble: I'm not sure how my pronunciation is more literal. I'd call it more abstract. But all this just supports my original contention that the question cannot be answered definitively.

Comment: @karthik In the US, "car" is the common name for any automobile, and the first thing that comes to mind.  That's most likely why that pronunciation is avoided for "char".  I switch between the "car" and "char"ming pronunciations based on my mood, and I don't own a car ;)

Comment: @Robusto: I'm just saying that the hard "k", whether it's expressed as *car* or *care*, clearly derives from "literal" abbreviation of the pronunciation of *character*. I must admit I'm intrigued by your version though, since I really have never come across it. I know I'd have remembered - even reading about it here strikes me as odd, so if I actually *heard* it I'd positively fall off my perch. Well, not now perhaps, since I'm forewarned, but I think I'll check a few more youtube clips just for the quirkiness of hearing it (I'm prepared to believe you that I *will* find one fairly easily! :)

Comment: Also, I think the part about "reg" should be a separate question, so I am going to edit it out of this question and answer. Please feel free to start a new question on that matter.

Comment: @Robusto: Yes yes, and there are (a lot of) people who pronounce SQL as "sequel," despite Microsoft, MySQL, and ANSI all officially/only pronouncing it "S-Q-L."  But I never correct anyone, especially database admins who would become bitter at me if I told them.

Comment: I was just thinking this very thing, as one of my very learned colleagues (a fellow database programmer) said *"I made that column a car-ten"* (for char(10)). I always say [tʃɑ:r] (bilingual native Canadian English speaker.)

Comment: Wouldn't Dennis Ritchie's pronunciation of it have to be correct? Unfortunately, I don't know what that is.

Comment: FumbleFingers be careful when you say "always". i'm a programmer who has never, ever pronounced it any way beside like the first syllable of *character* (because it's an abbreviation for *character* ...)

Comment: @PeterShor Dennis always said it as you might say *charred toast*. So did the rest of the labbies from Research at Murray Hill. You can ask any of those still alive what the cultural preference there was, like Doug McIlroy, Brian Kernighan, Ken Thompson, Rob Pike, Dave Presotto, Tom Duff, Andrew Hume,  — or Bjarne Stroustrup, mentioned in a comment below.

Comment: I've always pronounced "care", as the first syllable of "character".  And I've been programming since 1968.  But I've heard several other pronunciations.

Comment: You have to consider that most programmers in the world speak English only as a second language, so many things in the programming world don't make 100% sense to native English speakers.

Comment: Just a note as a long-time software engineer: When I first got started, the abbreviation didn't seem to exist conversationally until the C language showed up.  Back then, they were mostly called tch-ar (don't ask me to learn IPA), even though I always called them "care".  However that seemed to flip: Nowadays, the engineers I know _all_ refer to them as "care", or "cares".  BTW "gif" vs. "jif" flipped out there too.  Seems like most folks are hard-G on that one now when at first they were not.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

(Note this answer was previously posted to a question which has since been deleted on Programmers.stackexchange.com)

---

The abbreviated form *char*, short for *character*, can be pronounced in several different ways in American English: here's how you represent the various pronunciations in American English using the [International Phonetic Alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aIPA_for_English):

1. *char* as in ***char**-broiled:* /tʃɑr/
2. *char* as in ***car**:* /kɑr/
3. *char* as in ***char**acter:* /kær/
4. *char* as in ***care**:* /kɛr/

For many speakers of American English (including myself), the /æ/ sound before /r/ is merged with the /ɛ/ sound. That is, the words *marry* and *merry* are pronounced the same. For these people, #3 and #4 are indistinguishably pronounced like #4. People with this merger are often confused if someone else tries to explain the distinction between #3 and #4.

I have heard all these forms used and as a descriptivist, I would make no attempt to declare any as “correct”. Each has different arguments for and against, which I will enumerate below.

1. This form has the advantage of being “obvious”—that is, it is pronounced the way a naïve pronunciation of an unknown English word would be pronounced. It is also how the unrelated but identically spelled verb *char* is pronounced. On the downside, it preserves neither the initial /k/ sound nor the vowel of the word the abbreviation is derived from, *character*.
2. This form maintains the initial /k/ sound from *character* but is otherwise pronounced as spelled. It does not preserve the vowel from *character*.
3. This form maintains both the initial /k/ sound and the vowel from *character*. It is the most faithful to the source word. On the downside, /ær/ is not a phonotactically valid way for a word to end. The sequence /ær/ is only possible if there are additional vowels, as in *marry* or *character*. That is, if you say /kær/ as an independent word it is a violation of the normal phonotactic constraints of spoken English. Furthermore, it is a completely non-obvious pronunciation if you don’t already know that *char* is short for *character* and how *character* is pronounced.
4. This form is very similar to #3, being quite faithful to the underlying form, but with the advantage of not violating the phonotactic constraint against words ending in /ær/. For people with the *marry*–*merry* merger, it is not actually perceived to be different from #3 at all. On the downside, it is a completely non-obvious pronunciation if you don’t already know that *char* is short for *character* and how *character* is pronounced. Also, if you do distinguish #3 and #4, then #4 does not actually have the same vowel as *character*.

Each possible pronunciation has its own set of advantages and disadvantages, which is why there is a diversity of pronunciation in the field—there is no form that is clearly better than all the others. Furthermore, the different possibilities are bound up in a dialectical difference that most speakers of American English are unaware of, so when discussions of how to pronounce *char* come up, often two people are talking about dialectical differences when what they think they are talking about is a lexical difference.

Comment: I don't pronounce _marry_ and _merry_ the same, but I do pronounce _care_ and _char_acter the same.  It's definitely a very local accent thing, similar to how Chicagoans pronounce the "a" in Chicago differently than those who grew up in the west suburbs, less than an hour away.

Comment: A superb answer.

Comment: @Izkata, that’s quite interesting. I would tend to pronounce _marry_ and _merry_ the same, but I pronounce _care_ and _char(acter)_ differently, just like I pronounce _pair_ and _par(achute)_ with different vowels (the former with [ɛ], the latter with [æ]). Or more parallel: _carry_ [æ] vs. _carey_ [ɛ] (as in ‘someone who cares’).

Comment: In US English, many people do, in fact, pronounce "marry" and "merry" differently. The Americans you see on TV often have a flatter, West coast accent, where the two sound the same. In other words, it's a regional thing.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Many us neutralize [æɹ], [ɛɹ], [eɪɹ], [eɹ], [eəɹ]  to just plain [eɹ] is such syllables, and so /er/ is all we think of any of them as.

Answer (score 28):

I will reiterate what Bjarne Stroustrup has to say:

> "char" is usually pronounced "tchar", not "kar". This may seem illogical because "character" is pronounced "ka-rak-ter", but nobody ever accused English pronunciation (not "pronounciation" :-) and spelling of being logical.

http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#char

Answer (score 5):

> While trying to find the answer elsewhere, I learnt that there is an 
>       English word 'char' which is pronounced [tʃɑ:(r)], but it has nothing to do with characters.

I'm certain that this is why many people say **[tʃɑ:(r)]**.  To answer your question, I would say "[tʃɑ:(r)] a" when I read

`char a;`

I can't find the reference right now of course, but either one of my Java books or my teachers said that the person who thought of the `char` keyword pronounced it *care* because they were named/working with/obsessed with/father of someone named Karen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand your choice of redge-edit, but I don't understand redge-ex. The latter comes from regular exptression, so why would you pronounce it as redge-ex? Is it a common pronunciation? o_O

Comment: I was just expanding on my use of 'redge' when I see `reg` words, like `regex` for regular expressions and `regedit` for registry editor.

Comment: @Matt, how did you do that?  That type of look is what I wanted to use to quote the OP.

Comment: if you start a line with `>` then it will make the line a quote :)

Comment: Ohhh right.  And see, I use that all the time when I provide dictionary definitions.  It's Monday, alright.

Comment: I always say [tʃɑ:(r)], because I say char meaning tea as well, pronounced the same. I use redge-edit, but I say reg-ex. It makes sense to me, but it is clear that there re no hard and fast rules.

Comment: RE redge: If I see the boy's name "Reg", I pronounce it "rej" or "redj". But "regedit" I pronounce "reg-ed-it". Interesting. This leads me to what I am sure is a totally original observation: the relationship between English spelling and pronunciation is not entirely consistent.

Answer (score 4):

RE "char", I agree with karthik: I pronounce it like the first syllable of "character". I've heard people pronounce it "char", that is, pronounce the "ch" as in "chair" and then "ar" as in "car". This does bring up the question why we spell the word "character" and not "caracter" or "karacter". I think we should start a movement to change that.

It never occurred to me before that this looks just like "char" as in "burn slightly". I pronounce that with "ch" as in chair. I suppose that's not all that surprising, there are other words that are spelled the same but pronounced differently, like "polish", "rub something to make it shine, and "Polish", the nationality, the former has a short "o" and the latter a long "o".

Oh, it occurs to me that most people I talk to pronounce the SQL type "varchar" as "var-car", i.e. pronounce the "char" part to sound like "car" as in automobile and the "var" part to rhyme with it.

But all of this is anecdotal. I doubt I've heard more than a few dozen people pronounce these words, and all in a few small groups so they might easily have influenced each other. And I don't think Google Ngrams has pronunciations to get any large scale statistics.

Answer (score 2):

When reading code out loud, any phonetic pronunciation is for clarity of letter of the word, or more properly, the reserved word of the computer language.  It is therefore separate and distinct from any pronunciation of the word it abbreviates.

Therefore: (American English)
'char' 
the 'ch' as in church, change, charge, and march;
and the 'ar' as in car, far, mar, march, tar, and target;

or consider march, drop the m sound, and transpose the ar and ch for 'char'

I can not address how two (UK) English speakers would pronounce code.  They may use the proper word instead of pronouncing the abbreviation.

Comment: I can't make sense of your first sentence, but I think nohat covers everything.